# Как сделать, так чтоб функция выполнялась заново, если прошло некоторое время и она не выполнилась?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Использую Selenium и Python. Программа загружает страницу и делает разные действия на этой странице. Эту задачу я выполнил и обернул в функцию GetInfo(). Мне нужно сделать, так чтоб функция выполнялась заново, если прошло 2 минуты и она не выполнилась(это значит, сайт слишком долго грузится). Помогите пожалуйста это сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: А выполнение той, первой, функции должно приостанавливаться, когда запускается вторая?

Comment: нет, там везде только одна функция , GetInfo

Comment: Вы меня немного не поняли. Попробую подробнее: начинает выполняться функция. Выполняется долго. Она запускается снова, то есть запускается второй экземпляр одной и той же функции, ведь тот, первый экземпляр, всё ещё выполняется. Или нам нужно ПЕРЕзапускать один и тот же экземпляр функции при истечении таймаута?

Comment: Наша задача остановить работу функции, по истечению времени(2 минуты) и запустить его заново и делать это до тех пор пока функция не выполнится до конца. А если функция сработала успешно, то ничего не надо делать.

Answer (score 2):

Может имеется виду не функция, а контрено загрузка станицы?, тогда [set_page_load_timeout](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout)

```
def GetInfo(driver, url, retry=2):
    try :
        driver.get(url)
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException as _e:
        retry -= 1
        if retry:
            return GetInfo(driver, url, retry=retry)
    else:
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)  # если прошло 2 минуты и она не выполнилась(это значит, сайт слишком долго грузится)
    GetInfo(driver, url, retry=2)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это помогло решить проблему.